# Multiple conditions in Exist() clause of XQuery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I use XQuery in SQL Server and my question is: how to use two or more conditions in the `Exist()` clause?

For example:

```xml
[dbo].[A].[XmlList]:

<Property>
  <Value Name="Patt1">Pval1</Value>
  <Value Name="Patt1">Pval999</Value>
  <Value Name="patt2">Pval2</Value>
</Property>
```

Select query :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE XmlList.exist(N'/Property/Value [@Name="Patt1" and value="Pval1"]')
```

`@Name` is an attribute, and `value` is node value to look for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [@Name="Patt1"] expression to check an attribute value and then [text()="Pval1"] expression to check a node value.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE XmlList.exist(N'/Property/Value[@Name="Patt1"][text()="Pval1"]')=1
```

You also may use a nested structure like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE XmlList.exist(N'/Property[Value[@Name="Patt1"]="Pval1"]')=1
```

Expression Value[@Name="Patt1"] checks an attribute value.
Expression [Value[...]="Pval1"] checks a node value.

Comment: Thank . If there is a document for this, share it with me

Comment: You are welcome. Here you are the useful [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/).